# Не работают динамические URL в Django

Tags: django, url

Проще говоря, интернет-магазин.

Есть урлы (интересует 2):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^shops/$', views.shops, name='shops'), #просто страница со списком всех магазинов
url(r'^shops/astratech/$', views.astratech, name='astratech'), #страница с конкретным магазином (допустим, Астратек)
url(r'^shops/astratech/product/(?P<product_id>\w+)$', 
views.product_astratech, name='product_astratech'), #страница с конкретным товаром из магазина Астратек (допустим, shops/astratech/product/1 - первый продукт из магазина)
]
```

Вьюхи (интересует 2):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def shops(request): #Как видно, ничего нового
    title_page = "УНИТЕХСТРОЙ - Магазины"
    return render(request, 'shops.html', locals())

def astratech(request): #Здесь тоже ничего нового, просто фильтрует весь товар на то, что он принадлежит магазину Астратек)
    title_page = "Астратек"
    astra_prod = Products.objects.filter(Magazine=1)
    return render(request, 'shops/astratech.html', locals())

def product_astratech(request, product_id): #Вьюха для страницы конкретного продукта от магазина
    astra_prod = Products.objects.filter(Magazine=1)
    product = Products.objects.get(id=product_id)
    title_page = product.Name
    return render(request, 'shops/product_item.html', locals())
```

А теперь шаблоны:

shops/astratech.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

{% include 'shops/astra_item.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

Шаблон shops/astra_item.html (самый меня интересующий):

```
{% for astra_prod in astra_prod %}
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="product-item">
    <div>
            <img src="{{ astra_prod.Image.url }}" class="img-prod img-fluid">
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'product' product.id %}">Ссылка на товар</a>
    <h4 class="text-center">{{ astra_prod.Name }}</h4>
    <div class="block-price text-center">
        <h5>{{ astra_prod.Price }} руб. </h5>
        <p> 
    </div>

</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Суть проблемы в том, что не работает кусочек кода в astra_item.html, где идет ссылка на товар

```
<a href="{% url 'product' product.id %}">Ссылка на товар</a>
```

Ошибка:

```
NoReverseMatch at /shops/astratech/
Reverse for 'product' not found. 'product' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Честно, не понимаю в чем проблема, я уже делал подобный проект, если самому писать урл в адресной строке отдельного какого-либо продукта, то парсит нормально, а вот как в шаблоне пишу ссылку, ошибка и выскакивает

Comment: Так разве не `{% url 'product_astratech' product.id %}` должно быть?

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /shops/astratech/
    Reverse for 'product_astratech' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shops/astratech/product/(?P<product_id>\\w+)$']

Comment: Теперь такая проблема, если сделать как вы предложили

Comment: Внимательнее надо быть `{% url 'product_astratech' astra_prod.id %}`